# PHP library inside or outside of document root?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm writing a PHP library based on the zend framework. My library is used by several of my web projects. Im not sure where I should put my library. It seems to make sense to have it outside of the document root of the individual projects, so I don't have to maintain the library in every individual project. My current setup looks like this:

```
/var/www/vhosts/project1/
/var/www/vhosts/project2/
/var/www/vhosts/libraries/zend-framework/zend-framework-1.11.0/...
/var/www/vhosts/libraries/my-lib/my-lib-1.0.0/...
```

Like this, specific versions of both the zend-framework and my-lib can be used in my projects.

An alternative setup would look like this:

```
/var/www/vhosts/project1/
/var/www/vhosts/project1/libraries/zend-framework/zend-framework-1.11.0/...
/var/www/vhosts/project1/libraries/my-lib/my-lib-1.0.0/...
/var/www/vhosts/project2/
/var/www/vhosts/project2/libraries/zend-framework/zend-framework-1.11.0/...
/var/www/vhosts/project2/libraries/my-lib/my-lib-1.0.0/...
```

The first version makes more sense to me, but I'm not sure if I run into some security problems if my projects depend on files outside of their document root folders. Furthermore, I experience problems when I try to include javascript files from my-lib in my projects if my-lib is outside of the projects document root.

What's best practice here, where should I put my library and the zend framework?

Comment: /var/lib ? since it's a library ?

Comment: i dont think you can put javascript files outside the document root because then those will not be accessible from the browser.

Comment: I vote for the first. But when you're talking of project documentRoot I hope you're not talking of apache DocumentRoot, this would be a big security failure.

Comment: Yeah, if there are JS, what I wrote lower is useless. In that case if the library doesn't use sessions I'd suggest you put it on a different domain, otherwise you need to add your library at the root of each app using it. In that last case, I think a symbolic link to a same location should work.

Comment: Indeed, I just tried to add some js to my-lib and run into problems including it in my projects (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658974/including-a-javascript-file-outside-of-doc-root-using-zend-framework). Unfortunately, symbolic links are no good solution for me, since I use Xampp on Windows 7 to develop my web projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If /var/www/vhosts/libraries is accessible from outside, I'd recommend you put your library one level lower (/var/www/libraries) so:

1. you can share the same lib with all your PHP apps
2. PHP can access it without tweaking the rights
3. it's not directly accessible from the front sites

Comment: Concerning any public facing files in these libraries (js, css, images, etc.) you can use an Apache alias (mod_alias) to map these files to a reachable url.